# Check Meteor "Call Queue"

Tags: meteor

I may have the terminology wrong however I am looking for ways to check the queue of meteor.call functions that are being retried due to a user being offline.

Some context: I have a system that allows users to book appointments in a diary.  Some users with (very) poor wifi coverage are seeing appointments appear however subsequently disappear and it seems this is due to them being created when offline and then the page reloaded / disconnected before the page comes back online or before the local and remote data are synced. I have implemented an approach to inform the user that they are offline and as such should not change / reload the page however I would like to be able to check this queue so that once the connection is back, I know how long to wait until it has caught up.